# Javascript inside RSS file

Tags: javascript, rss, google-analytics

I've been given a requirement to impliment some google tracking on an RSS feed. Currently we track when users click the RSS link but they also seem to want to track access to the RSS feed outside of that link.

I could impliment this server side but I'm just wondering whether putting google tracking code (Javascript) inside of an RSS (XML) file will actually be parsed by the browser at runtime.

Comment: not really an answer, but have a look at FeedBurner.com (now part of Google). It tracks your RSS usage, and gives a lot of statistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The only agent that will execute JavaScript inside an RSS file is a web RSS interface with a security hole.

Comment: I thought (and hoped) as much. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, RSS is an XML data type. JavaScript is not valid inside of it. It'll have to be done serverside.